# acts_as_votable vote count playing crazy when 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined a simple **Upvote - Downvote** format using [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable):

```
  # Upvote
  def upvote
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to @question
  end

  # Downvote
  def downvote
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to @question
  end
```

In my **show.html.erb** i'm trying to *sum up* the votes by:

```
<%= @question.upvotes.size - @question.downvotes.size %>
```

And somewhat around here i lost the logic.. I'm upvoting from 2 different accounts so that
the count is at **2**. All cool. But if (from any account) i downvote just once - the counter resets to **0** instead of **1**.

And if i downvote from the other account too the counter goes to **-2** instead of **-1**

What am i missing?